# Conditional sentence with neither nor

Tags: grammaticality

"It has no link wih proverty. Because if it was then neither this engineer or designer join this radical group." Is this a gramatically correct sentence?if not,then please let me know how this can be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Original text:

> "It has no link wih proverty. Because if it was then neither this engineer or designer join this radical group."

Corrected text:

> “It has no link with poverty, because if it did, then neither this engineer nor this designer would join this radical group.”

Corrections:

1. Uncapitalize “because.”
2. Add a comma before “because.”
3. Add a comma after “did.”
4. Replace “or” with “nor” between “this engineer” and “this designer.”
5. Add “would” before the verb “join” because the preceding “if” makes the clause a subjunctive clause.

[www.web.cn.edu](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/grammar_subjunctive.html) states,

> 1. By far the most common use of the subjunctive is the use of the subjunctive after "if" clauses that state or describe a hypothetical situation.
>
>    > Subjunctive: "If I were a butterfly, I would have wings."

(Without knowing the context, I suppose “that radical group” may also be possible.)

Comment: Perhaps "had" instead of "did" and "have joined" instead of "join".

Comment: @RichardKayser - I agree.